# How to pass list of string in UDF function in big query?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to pass 'n' number of string in through UDF function but it shows error what to do

This is my code:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getDataOfTheseKeys(x ANY TYPE)
AS (
  SELECT * FROM TABLE keys IN (x)
)

SELECT * FROM getDataOfTheseKeys("key1","key2","key3")
```

This is not working..

Comment: Can you give us more context of what you trying to do? Input data and expected output?

Comment: Why don't you pass an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you an example with an `array` as parameter of the `udf` :

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getDataOfTheseKeys(arr ANY TYPE)
AS (

  (select array_agg(id) from `project.dataset.table` where id IN UNNEST(arr))
);

SELECT
  getDataOfTheseKeys(x) AS el
FROM (
  SELECT ['ecaff28db267', '452094b23ee1', 'ecavf28db269'] AS x
);
```

In my example `ecaff28db267` and `452094b23ee1` exist in the table but not `ecavf28db269`

The result in this case is :

`Array` of `String` =>

```
ecaff28db267
452094b23ee1
```